# How can I automate the deletion of all files in a specific folder on a daily basis?

Tags: windows, script

I have a media center and I would like to set up a script/automation that deletes all files in a specific folder once a day.  I know that I can do this in the Microsoft Task Scheduler with a .bat script but I am not very familiar with scripting and I am not sure how to go about this.  I would know how to delete one file but I do not know how to delete all files in a folder.  I would like to achieve this without deleting the folder as well.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: " I would know how to delete one file but I do not know how to delete all files in a folder" -- Typing `del /?` at a command prompt shall enlighten you.

Answer (score 2):

Say your folder is `c:\temp\media`. To delete all files inside that folder:

```
del /q c:\temp\media\*
```

Put this in a batch file, copy some files there and test with Task Scheduler. When you are sure it works as you expect, put the real media folder instead of `c:\temp\media`.

Notes:

- The above will not delete the folder itself, i.e. after deleting files inside `c:\temp\media`, you will still have the folder (i.e. `c:\temp\media`) itself
- The above will delete only files, not folders. If you need to delete folders, see this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502913/how-to-delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-folder-by-cmd-call

- Probably worth checking with somebody else who could help you with setting up, just so you don't delete stuff you don't want to :)